# Before showing next div on click check atleast 1 checkbox should be checked

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have following requirement, before showing next div have to check atleast 1 checkbox or radio should be checked is must.
it is done but, If user select window ac & select all 4 services then on nxet button should be ask for no of unist for all selected services. At last booknow button display. If he select 2 services then it ask no of units for both selected service If he select both window & split ac & then select no of services then it ask user no of units for selected services for both type window & split.

Thanks in advance.

My code as follows

```
 <div class="container quick-box-outer">
            <div class="voffset-7">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-warning first current" id="step1">
                        <div class="panel-heading">What we provide</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="services-list">
                                <li>Background checked and trained technicians</li>
                                <li>30 days service guarantee</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-heading">Pricing</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="services-list">
                                <li>Fixed charges for installation, uninstallation and servicing</li>
                                <li>Charges for AC repairs will be quoted upon inspection</li>
                                <li>Rs.199 inspection charges if no service is availed post inspection</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning" id="step2" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">What do you need?</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="windowac" id="windowac" class="mychk">
                                    <label for="windowac"> Window AC</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="select-product last">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="splitac" name="fliptac" class="mychk">
                                    <label for="splitac">Split AC</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning" id="step3" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">What type of service do you want?</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form id="step2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="wetservice" id="wetservice" class="mychk">
                                        <label for="wetservice"> Wet Servicing (Jet pump service not included)</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="dryservice" id="dryservice">
                                        <label for="dryservice"> Dry Servicing</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="gas" id="gas">
                                        <label for="gas"> Gas Charging</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product last">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other">
                                        <label for="other"> Other repairs</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-warning last" id="step4" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">How many ACs need Wet servicing?</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form id="step2">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <label for="1unit">
                                            <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="1unit"> 1</span>
                                            <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <label for="2unit">
                                            <span class="col-md-6"> <input type="radio" name="units" id="2unit"> 2</span>
                                            <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <label for="3unit">
                                            <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="3unit"> 3</span>
                                            <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product">
                                        <label for="4unit">
                                            <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="4unit"> 4</span>
                                            <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="select-product last">
                                        <label for="5unit">
                                            <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="5unit"> 5</span>
                                            <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning last" id="step5" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">How many ACs need Dry servicing?</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="1unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="1unit"> 1</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="2unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"> <input type="radio" name="units" id="2unit"> 2</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="3unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="3unit"> 3</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="4unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="4unit"> 4</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product last">
                                    <label for="5unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="5unit"> 5</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning last" id="step6" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">How many ACs need Gas Charging</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="1unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="1unit"> 1</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="2unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"> <input type="radio" name="units" id="2unit"> 2</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="3unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="3unit"> 3</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="4unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="4unit"> 4</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product last">
                                    <label for="5unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="5unit"> 5</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-warning last" id="step7" style="display:none">
                        <div class="panel-heading">How many ACs need other reparing</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="1unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="1unit"> 1</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="2unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"> <input type="radio" name="units" id="2unit"> 2</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="3unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="3unit"> 3</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product">
                                    <label for="4unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="4unit"> 4</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="select-product last">
                                    <label for="5unit">
                                        <span class="col-md-6"><input type="radio" name="units" id="5unit"> 5</span>
                                        <span class="col-md-6 text-right">Rs 500</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning" id="prev" style="display:none;">Back</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning pull-right" id="next">Next</a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning pull-right" id="booknow" style="display:none;">Book Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#next').click(function() {

        if ($('.current').find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 0 && !$('.current :checked').length) {
            alert('Select one or more options to Continue')
            return;
        }
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .next().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('last')) {
            $('#next').hide();
            $('#booknow').show();
        }
        $('#prev').show();
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $('#booknow').hide();
        $('.current').removeClass('current').hide()
            .prev().show().addClass('current');
        if ($('.current').hasClass('first')) {
            $('#prev').hide();
        }
        $('#next').show();
    });

</script>
<script>
    $('#booknow').click(function() {
        if ($('.current').find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 0 && !$('.current :checked').length) {
            alert('Select one or more options to Continue')
            return;
        }
        window.location = "checkout.html"
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether current box have radio elements and checkboxes in it, if yes then check for length of checked element. Like this:

```
if( $('.current').find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 0  &&  !$('.current :checked').length){
   alert('check atleast one item')
   return;
}
```

Above snippet needs to be added in both next button click and book now button click handlers.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxhun05c/)**

Comment: Hello Milind,
Its working for all "next" buttons but its not working for "Book Now" button

Comment: @Vishaal: you need to add click event for book now button. do the redirection when above condition is met.

Comment: @Vishaal : Because , the validation is for button with `id = next` and not `id="booknow"`

Comment: Hello Milind,  I have add click even and its working now.

Comment: @Vishaal: that's great...don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Hello Milind,
Pls help me to achive this

Comment: @Vishaal: what is the issue?

Comment: @Milind, Atleast check 1 radio or checkbox issue is resolved as per your code, but now if user select both all types of services, then no of units div should be show as per selected services check box
If user select all 4 services then it will show no of units 4 times

If user select both types of ac window &split & select no of services check box then no of unit should show as per selected checkboxes of both types

Comment: @Vishaal: can you elaborate this with fiddle.

Comment: ok, wait , or better you can refer this link, https://www.urbanclap.com/request/ac_service_repair?source=home_search
select any tupe of ac, select no of servicing then see no of units div

Comment: @ Milind check this fiddle &  link
https://jsfiddle.net/vishaalmandge/b4naqL1n/

https://www.urbanclap.com/request/ac_service_repair?source=home_search

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this u can check based on length 
`$('.current').find(':checkbox,:radio').length`

https://plnkr.co/edit/98wqVnVnBMvlh1idgM94?p=preview

Comment: Its working for all NEXT butoons, But not working for "Book now" Button

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($('.current input[type=checkbox]:checked').length)
            {
                //go next
            } else
            {
              alert('select atleast one checkbox')
            }
```